# Timeout on some connections (OpenBSD/PF with NAT)

Tags: timeout, openbsd, pf

I am getting "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT" on chrome for certain sites only (e.g. www.lemonde.fr). This does not happen when I use a proxy or if I access the site from my firewall.

For the context, I use OpenBSD 5.3 on a soekris with PF.

```
Internet
||
Fiber on ethernet modem
|vr0|
soekris
|vr1|-|vr2|-|vr3|
PCs    PCs   PCs
```

My configuration is below (I tried a lot so it's a little messy)

```
set skip on lo
set block-policy return
set debug misc
set ruleset-optimization basic


match in all scrub (no-df)

antispoof quick for pppoe0

block all

block in log quick from urpf-failed

block in quick on vr0 proto tcp from any to any port ssh
block in quick on pppoe0 proto tcp from any to any port ssh
block in quick on pppoe0 proto tcp from any to any port smtp

pass on tun0 from any to 10.0.0.0/24

pass in on vr1 from 192.168.10.0/24
pass out on vr1 to 192.168.10.0/24

pass in on vr2 from 192.168.9.0/24
pass out on vr2 to 192.168.9.0/24

pass in on vr3 from 192.168.8.0/24
pass out on vr3 to 192.168.8.0/24

#let soekris go online
pass out on pppoe0 from !(vr0) to any keep state

match out on tun0 from any to 10.0.0.0/24 nat-to (tun0)
match out on pppoe0 inet from !(pppoe0:network) to any nat-to (pppoe0:0) 


#establish keep-state pass
```

From what I saw with pflog, my connections are going outside and states exist but there is no packet in return. Since this only happen to some websites, it is harder for me to understand.

I hope someone can help me, since it's been 2 weeks I use a proxy to use Internet correctly (-.-;)

THanks,

ALex

Answer (score 0):

OpenBSD 5.3 is quite old.  You might find your issue is resolved simply be upgrading to the current release.

Comment: Thanks for answer but updating on a soekris may not be easy since I don't have screen, I need to connect on com port. 

The firewall was working well until i reboot it 2 weeks ago, there was probably a diff between running conf and pf.conf. Do you see something strange in conf?

Comment: Sometimes PPP connection have MTU issues.  See man pppoe 4 for details and how to resolve.